# How can we use Apple Provider with Spring Security oauth2 client

Tags: spring, security, spring-security-oauth2, apple-sign-in, oauth-provider

I need to use Apple_Sign_In option with other Google, Facebook sign in options. Even though Apple is adopted the existing open standards OAuth 2.0 and OpenID Connect (Hybrid Flow). It's difficult to get it work by simply changing the .yml configurations as described in [GitHub fix for raised issue.](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9047#issuecomment-701516346).

I have tried [Customizing oauth request](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-custom-oauth-requests) approach and I am stuck on reading Authorization code which is sent in body to use for token exchange and get logged user details(Apple does not support userInfoUri.)

More details can be found on [github_comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9047#issuecomment-785031635)
Can someone share a working code example how can we use Apple Sign In with oauth2 client ?

Comment: check this : https://medium.com/tekraze/adding-apple-sign-in-to-spring-boot-app-java-backend-part-e053da331a